# are there any other distinguishing characteristics for waves?

Tags: waves

This [post](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/waves/Lesson-1/Categories-of-Waves) distinguish Waves as 2 styles:

1. Longitudinal versus Transverse Waves versus Surface Waves
2. Electromagnetic versus Mechanical Waves

are there any other distinguishing characteristics?

Comment: Shape, maybe? What are you looking for, specifically?

Comment: Dimensionality: 1D, 2D, 3D, etc. For sinusoidal waves: wavelength, frequency, and speed. For non-sinusoidal waves: the waveform and the frequency distribution. Planar vs. spherical vs. other angular distributions. Polarization: planar, circular, etc. Linear vs. nonlinear (e.g., solitons).  Scalar wave vs. spinor wave vs. vector wave vs. tensor wave. Real vs. complex  (e.g. wavefunction). Number-valued vs. operator valued (e.g., quantum field theory). This is not a complete list but it gives you the idea that waves come in *lots* of variants!

Comment: BTW, this site doesn’t like “Big List” questions (or answers) so your question might get downvoted or closed, and my comment above might get deleted. PSE wants *narrowly focused* conceptual questions with one correct answer.

Comment: @G.Smith Thanks for your reminder. How about [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/527368/252362)? Is it a sort of “Big List” question?

Comment: Yes, it is in my opinion.